# pandas, multiply all the numeric values in the data frame by a constant

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

How to multiply all the numeric values in the data frame by a constant without having to specify column names explicitly? Example:

```
In [13]: df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': ['A','B','C'], 'col2':[1,2,3], 'col3': [30, 10,20]})

In [14]: df
Out[14]: 
  col1  col2  col3
0    A     1    30
1    B     2    10
2    C     3    20
```

I tried `df.multiply` but it affects the string values as well by concatenating them several times.

```
In [15]: df.multiply(3)
Out[15]: 
  col1  col2  col3
0  AAA     3    90
1  BBB     6    30
2  CCC     9    60
```

Is there a way to preserve the string values intact while multiplying only the numeric values by a constant?

Comment: Is there any reason to avoid column names?

Comment: Large dataframe with mixed textual and numeric fields. @ganesshkumar

Answer (score 35, accepted):

you can use [select_dtypes()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.select_dtypes.html) including `number` dtype or  excluding all columns of `object` and `datetime64` dtypes:

Demo:

```
In [162]: df
Out[162]:
  col1  col2  col3       date
0    A     1    30 2016-01-01
1    B     2    10 2016-01-02
2    C     3    20 2016-01-03

In [163]: df.dtypes
Out[163]:
col1            object
col2             int64
col3             int64
date    datetime64[ns]
dtype: object

In [164]: df.select_dtypes(exclude=['object', 'datetime']) * 3
Out[164]:
   col2  col3
0     3    90
1     6    30
2     9    60
```

or a much better solution (c) [ayhan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38543263/pandas-multiply-all-the-numeric-values-in-the-data-frame-by-a-constant/38543323?noredirect=1#comment64478587_38543323):

```
df[df.select_dtypes(include=['number']).columns] *= 3
```

From [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.melt.html):

> To select all numeric types use the numpy dtype numpy.number

Comment: To operate on the original dataframe, you can modify that to: `df[df.select_dtypes(include=['number']).columns] *= 3`

Comment: @ayhan, thank you! I've added your solution to my answer as it might help those who doesn't read comments... :)

Comment: I am just wondering as a sort of random thought that I am having lately : Is it fair to answer pandas questions with NumPy funcs? I mean I don't mind, but I am guessing the OPs won't either and would have access to NumPy too, at least if I remember when installing pandas library ;) Also, since pandas uses NumPy internally, does this look like hacking/cheating?BTW I am referring to my posts on pandas.

Comment: @Divakar, i do love your NumPy solutions for pandas questions, especially when they are orders of magnitude faster ;)

Comment: @Divakar OP can select whatever answer they want. After that the community, we, vote as we please. I feel that your numpy-ness is always welcome.

Comment: @piRSquared, MaxU Thanks guys, really appreciate the feedback and positive assurance there!

Answer (score 7):

The other answer specifies how to multiply only numeric columns. Here's how to update it:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': ['A','B','C'], 'col2':[1,2,3], 'col3': [30, 10,20]})

s = df.select_dtypes(include=[np.number])*3

df[s.columns] = s

print (df)

  col1  col2  col3
0    A     3    90
1    B     6    30
2    C     9    60
```

Answer (score 4):

One way would be to get the `dtypes`, match them against `object` and `datetime` dtypes and exclude them with a mask, like so -

```
df.ix[:,~np.in1d(df.dtypes,['object','datetime'])] *= 3
```

Sample run -

```
In [273]: df
Out[273]: 
  col1  col2  col3
0    A     1    30
1    B     2    10
2    C     3    20

In [274]: df.ix[:,~np.in1d(df.dtypes,['object','datetime'])] *= 3

In [275]: df
Out[275]: 
  col1  col2  col3
0    A     3    90
1    B     6    30
2    C     9    60
```

Answer (score 3):

This should work even over mixed types within columns but is likely slow over large dataframes.

```
def mul(x, y):
    try:
        return pd.to_numeric(x) * y
    except:
        return x

df.applymap(lambda x: mul(x, 3))
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution using `assign()` and `select_dtypes()`:

`df.assign(**df.select_dtypes('number')*3)`